# JPQL Group By as Distinct

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Lets assume I have the following entities (annotations/getters setters ommitted):

```
@Entity
public class Topic {

   @Id
   private Long id;
      private String title;
   private String text;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
   private List<Post> posts = new LinkedList();

}

@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String text;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date updatedOn;

    @ManyToOne
    private Topic topic;
}
```

I want to run a `JPQL` query that basically sorts the `Topics` according to the most recent `Post`.

So the query I have created is as follows:

```
select t from Topic t join t.posts p
group by t, p
order by p.updatedOn desc
```

However **the issue here is that I have duplicate Topic entities**. Not even using `select distinct` works.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
SELECT
  topic0_.id               AS id1_13_,
  topic0_.text             AS text_r5_13_,
  topic0_.title            AS title7_13_
FROM topic topic0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN post posts1_
    ON topic0_.id = posts1_.topic_id

GROUP BY topic0_.id, posts1_.id
ORDER BY posts1_.updated_on DESC
```

Comment: The SQL invoked is ?

Comment: Show the complete code of your entities Topic and Post, not ommiting the JPA annotations. Do you try to use `Set` instead of `List` to map the posts on entity Topic? Like `Set<Post> posts;`.

Comment: Have you tried just grouping by `t` and not `t,p`?

Comment: Yes, if I group only by t, then I can't order by p. Using Set instead of List doesn't work either.